# JBoss 7 - how to configure the logging of my application on the jboss server

Tags: logging, jboss7.x

Currently my web application (Jboss 7.1.1, Hibernate 3.6.9, Spring 3.0.1) used log4j for logging.

log4j.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<appender name="application" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/my.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d{ABSOLUTE}|%5p|%c{1}:%L|%X{ipAddress}|%X{deviceId} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="duration" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/my-duration.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="%d{ABSOLUTE}|%5p|%c{1}:%L|%X{ipAddress}|%X{deviceId} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>


<logger name="com.my">
    <level value="debug" />
</logger>

<logger name="com.my.xx.PerformanceLogger"
    additivity="false">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="duration" />
</logger>

<root>
    <priority value="error" />
    <appender-ref ref="application" />
</root>
```

This is working but now I must switch to server configured logging. How can I do this? Already tried out on JBoss Application Server console adding my handlers (core/logging/handler --> add) and afterwards defined logger categories. But this defined log files misses all(?) logger information from classes where I used:

```
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger
        .getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "But this defined log files misses all(?) logger information from classes"? If I understand it correctly you might just need to change the format pattern.

Comment: I meant that my defined log files just contains informations which are also found in the server.log but no loging informations from my classes (no LOGGER.info("xxx"), no LOGGER.WARN("xx")).